# Integration Theorem

Tags: analysis

If $f, g: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ are Riemann Integrable and g is bounded. Define: $m = inf_{x \in [a,b]} f(x)$ and $M = sup_{x \in [a,b]} f(x)$ implies there exists $\mu \in [m,M]$ such that 
$$\int_a^b f(x)g(x) dx = \mu \int_a^b g(x) dx$$

I got the case where g is positively bounded and when it is zero, but g is negative for some number, I'm having trouble. Any help.

Comment: What do you mean with "$g$ is bounded for some negative number"?

Comment: This is very difficult to read. Please learn to typeset correctly.

Comment: It works if $g$ keeps a constant sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let

$$f(x)=g(x)=\cos(x)$$

then

$$\int_0^{\pi} f(x)g(x)dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

and

$$\int_0^{\pi} g(x)dx=0$$

thus, $\,\mu\,$ doesn't exist in this case.